# Error: Found multiple IonicModule.forRoot calls in"imports". Only one is allowed

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I just cloned a Github repository and installed its packages. But when I ran `ionic serve` I had this error. I checked my `npm: 3.5.2` and `nodejs: v8.10.0`. My desktop OS is `Ubuntu 18.04LTS`.

So far I've tried deleting reinstalling every package and reinstall ionic client. Also, I checked my `app.module.ts` and the import from `ionic-angular` is:

`import { IonicApp, IonicModule, IonicErrorHandler } from 'ionic-angular';`

I wonder what does it exactly mean by forRoot in error and how do I solve this issue?

```
[09:10:20]  ionic-app-script task: "serve"
[app-scripts] [09:10:20]  Error: Found multiple IonicModule.forRoot calls in"imports". Only one is allowed
[app-scripts] Error: Found multiple IonicModule.forRoot calls in "imports". Only one is allowed
[app-scripts]     at new BuildError (/home/...../node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/util/errors.js:16:28)
[app-scripts]     at /home/..../node_modules/@ionic/app-scripts/dist/deep-linking.js:57:21
[app-scripts]     at <anonymous>

[ERROR] ionic-app-scripts has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).

        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IonicModule.forRoot(appRoot, config, deepLinkConfig)` is set the root app component for you IonicModule.

If you set it, you may need remove `bootstrap: [AppComponent]`.

Or set `IonicModule.forRoot()`, without parameters.

Look at [IonicModule](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/IonicModule/).

Comment: Thank you for your quick response!  However, I tried both propose methods but the error persists. Also, for `removing app comonent` method I got this red underline error: `ts] Expected 1-3 arguments, but got 0. [2554]
module.d.ts(58, 20): An argument for 'appRoot' was not provided.
(alias) class IonicModule
import IonicModule
@name — IonicModule

@description
IonicModule is an NgModule that bootstraps an Ionic App. By passing a root component, IonicModule will make sure that all of the components, directives, and providers from the framework are imported.`

Comment: nvm I solved the problem using the source you provided. Thanks a lot:)